# Enable http port in FI-Lab

Tags: filab

Could some one help me with the following issue? I need to enable the port 80 in my webserver on FI-Lab to allow public access, how could I do that?

I am currently using the FI-Lab platform at http://lab.fi-ware.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the more common problems when users have to deploy a server is that they have to specify previously the security group that the server has to use. In this security group, is mandatory that you specify the port that you want to use, in order that this port will be opened afterward in the server that you want to deploy.

If no security group is specified, by default all ports will be closed and you cannot access to the port 80 or access to the server via SSH using the default port 22 or whatever port that you want to use in your instantiate server.